# Makefile: Find and replace text in .txt file

Tags: sed, makefile

```
objects = foo.txt bar.txt

all: $(objects)

$(objects): %.txt: %.txt
        sed -e '/foo/bar' < $< > out_dir/$@
```

I get the error of circular dependency being dropped. Obviously If I change extension to like

```
objects = foo.txt2 bar.txt2

all: $(objects)

$(objects): %.txt2: %.txt
sed -e '/foo/bar' < $< > out_dir/$@
```

then it works

Comment: What is `/foo/bar` supposed to do?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `cmake`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to define your sources and create the object list with names including the directory part from that.

Example:

```
SRC = foo.txt bar.txt
OBJS = $(SRC:%.txt=out_dir/%.txt)

all: $(OBJS)

out_dir/%.txt: %.txt
        sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' < $< > $@
```

This would change from `foo` to `bar` in both `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` and place the result in files in `out_dir` with the same basenames as the source files has.

The main difference is that the **target** isn't depending on itself (the circular dependency), so the target `out_dir/foo.txt` depends on `foo.txt` and `out_dir/bar.txt` depends on `bar.txt`.